# Questions about Django's internationalization framework

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

When developing apps for use in multiple languages, I see a real benefit to using localization over trying to build some ad hoc localization library specific to your application. I'm working on a website that will have 16 languages, and each language will have different images in various places, as well as full text translations for each page's content, each language residing on a different URL (www.example.com/en/, etc). Django's internationalization framework seems very magical, and tricky. My idea was to do something basic, like:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2)  # (e.g. "FR")


class ContentSection(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey('mysite.Page')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # (e.g. ("main body text")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'page'),)


class ContentTranslation(models.Model):
    content_section = models.ForeignKey(ContentSection)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('content_section', 'language'),)
```

I would use middleware to set the current language based on the first URL segment, and in my views I would pull the content for a given page in a view with something like:

```
# In views.view_page
left_content = ContentSection.objects.filter(page=current_page, name='left column text')
if not request.language.code == 'EN':
    left_content = ContentTranslation.objects.get(content_section=left_content, language=request.language)
```

Of course, in production I'd probably create a template tag that gets a content (with the correct language) by name, instead of explicitly pulling each content area in the view.

Does this seem so ridiculous to do this instead of using i18n? Am I missing the bigger picture with internationalization?

(keep in mind: the site will be browsed by users in other languages, but all admin stuff, including inserting translations, will be done in the US)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sound approach if what you need is to be able to have your users change the content in all the different languages. You also get to create a nice interface for everything.

However, you are not using the Django i18n framework. So what is your question? :)

I have tried both using the i18n framework for content and using your approach. Storing translations in po-files is great for "system" text as you can use all your tools, like version control, bug tracking, etc. However, it is a pain in the ass if you have users who actually want to change the content all the time, which I believe is the case for almost any web site of some size.

As a side note, including the language in the URL makes it easier to cache the pages on the front end varnish proxy that everybody should be using, so +1 for that decision.

Comment: My question is really, why should I use i18n instead of using this approach?

Comment: You should not. The i18n framework is for text that belongs to the system, and not the content itself. For example error messages, section headers, footers, system messages to users, etc. You can also use it to format dates, datetimes, numbers, currency, etc.

Comment: Ok, I guess from my brief reading of the docs I thought that l10n was for that, but I guess l10n is more for interface language features, such as the names of model fields, forms, etc then. I have some reading to do.

Comment: i10n is for dates, numbers, currency, etc. i18n is for translating text in your application. My bad.